# How to convert from world coordinates to camera coordinates

Tags: 3d

In the world coordinate system, there are objects with rotation values `rx1,ry1,rz1` and position values `px1,py1,pz1`.

Similarly, there is an object in the world coordinate system with rotation values `rx2,ry2,rz2` and position values `px2,py2,pz2`.

What formula can be used to convert `rx1,ry1,rz1,px1,py1,pz1` to the camera coordinate system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "rotation values"? I don't think that's a standard term.

Comment: There's a computer graphics stackexchange: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ that might be more helpful.